# IndexError: List index out of range (python)

Tags: python

Выдает ошибку (`File "мой путь", line 118, in <module> main(sys.qrgv[1] IndexError: List index out of range`), после запуска bat файла, который должен запустить несколько .ру

```
omtl = open("%s/master.mtl" % (folder), "w")
for mat in data["materials"]:
    name = mat["name"]
    diffuse = mat["albedoTex"]
    # specular = mat["extrasTex"]

    # write to file
    omtl.write("newmtl {0}\n".format(name))
    omtl.write("map_Ka {0}\n".format(diffuse))
    omtl.write("map_Kd {0}\n".format(diffuse))
    # omtl.write("map_Ks {0}\n\n".format(specular))

omtl.close()

for mesh in data["meshes"]:
    name = mesh["name"]
    dat = mesh["file"]
    print("converting %s" % dat)
    # transform = mesh["transform"]
    wire_count = mesh["wireCount"]
    index_count = mesh["indexCount"]
    vertex_count = mesh["vertexCount"]

    tex_coord_2 = 0
    if "secondaryTexCoord" in mesh:
        tex_coord_2 = mesh["secondaryTexCoord"]

    vertex_color = 0
    if "vertexColor" in mesh:
        vertex_color = mesh["vertexColor"]

    index_type_size = mesh["indexTypeSize"]
    # consts
    stride = 32
    if vertex_color > 0: stride = stride + 4
    if tex_coord_2 > 0: stride = stride + 8

    # TODO: BUG LONG INDICES
    # if index_type_size == 4:
    #     raise Exception("ERROR! Currently can't process any large files with long (uint32) indices... To Be Updated!!!")

    # read stream
    df = open("%s/%s" % (folder, dat), "rb")
    # write stream
    output = open("{0}/{1}.obj".format(folder, dat), "w")
    output.write("mtllib master.mtl\n")

    # lists
    face_list = []
    vert_list = []
    uv_list = []
    materials_list = []

    for sub_mesh in mesh["subMeshes"]:
        faces = []
        material = sub_mesh["material"]
        index_count_2 = sub_mesh["indexCount"]
        wire_count_2 = sub_mesh["wireIndexCount"]

        face_count = int((index_count_2 * index_type_size) / 6)
        if index_type_size == 4:
            face_count = int((index_count_2 * index_type_size) / 12)

        # faces
        for f in range(face_count):
            if index_type_size == 2:
                faces.append(unpack("<HHH", df.read(6)))
            else:
                faces.append(unpack("<III", df.read(12)))

        # set submesh data
        face_list.append(faces)
        materials_list.append(material)

    # skip unknown wire count
    df.seek(wire_count * index_type_size, 1)

    # vertices
    for v in range(vertex_count):
        # position
        pos = unpack("<fff", df.read(12))
        # texcoord
        texpos = unpack("<ff", df.read(8))
        # stride
        df.read(stride - 20)

        vert_list.append(pos)
        uv_list.append(texpos)

    for vert in vert_list:
        output.write("v {0} {1} {2}\n".format(vert[0], vert[1], vert[2]))

    for uv in uv_list:
        output.write("vt {0} {1}\n".format(uv[0], uv[1]))

    for x, faces in enumerate(face_list):
        output.write("\n")
        output.write("g {0}\n".format(name))
        output.write("usemtl {0}\n".format(materials_list[x]))

        for face in faces:
            output.write("f {0}/{0}/{0} {1}/{1}/{1} {2}/{2}/{2}\n".format(face[0]+1, face[1]+1, face[2]+1))

    df.close()
    output.close()

print("COMPLETED!!!")
```

Comment: `sys.qrgv[1]`? Текст ошибки руками, что ли, набирали? Исключение возникает из-за того, что скрипт ожидает как минимум один аргумент из командной строки, но его не получает.

Comment: Спасибо, буду искать в этом направлении. Я новичок в этом.